# eCommerce Tracking With Tag Manager Showing in dataLayer but no in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I have setup a test page here http://thiswebguy.com/wrdtest/transaction-thanks.html which uses the example code found on the GTM help section.

I have checked the console and the product data is in the dataLayer, I have also used GADebugger and it says that the product has been sent to Analytics 'Tacking Beacon Sent' (it also lists the products and transaction info).

So I would assume that it would work and begin to show in Analytics.... But it's not!

I have added the event trackTransaction to the beginning:

```
'event': 'trackTransaction',
```

This isn't in the Google docs but it didn't work without it, and although it still doesn't now all the data is still showing in the dataLayer and GA Debugger.

I have two rules which fires when the event 'trackTransaction' is triggered; and to only fire once the dom is loaded.

In my previous setup I had two tags also one was the 'only fire when dom is loaded' tag and the other was fire only on the thank you page - but it gave me the same results as using the event.

I've waited two days for the data to show by the way.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out why, you actually need to type: dataLayer into the console.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're placing the dataLayer object in the `<body>`. Try moving it to the `<head>` and removing your `'event':'trackTransaction'`, and just have set your rule to fire on the `{{url}}` equals /thank-you-page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
dataLayer = [{
    'transactionId': '1234',
    'transactionAffiliation': 'Acme Clothing',
    'transactionTotal': '11.99',
    'transactionTax': '1.29',
    'transactionShipping': '5',
    'transactionProducts': [{
        'sku': 'DD44',
        'name': 'Test Prod',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'price': '11.99',
        'quantity': '1'
    },{
        'sku': 'AA1243544',
        'name': 'Test Prod Again',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'price': '9.99',
        'quantity': '2'
    }]
}];
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- GTM Container Code -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is invalid code. You can't simply put the datalyer in the head as you have written. It must be within a <script> tag. Also, you should put it in the <body> per Google's recommendation.

Comment: You're correct. I forgot the <script> tags. However, the dataLayer should go in the <head> or above the container, per [Google's recommendation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#datalayer).

Comment: I will admit that Google is a bit ambiguous. They say head in the text, but their "Correct" example code shows it below the opening <body> tag. This area is where the page *header* is typically rendered. Looking at all of the example code posted by Google, it's more likely that they didn't mean to place it within the <head> tag, but rather the header area of the page.